# while loop over takes the each method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding element to page using the static number according to the click of user. so the element has the serial number according to the user click.

when user click on any of the element and deletes, i need to re-arrange the serial number. i try using the each operator with while loop, but not working.

any one suggest me the right way pelase.

here is my try:

```
var num = this.clipsLength, clipNum=1;

            while(this.clipsLength > 0){

                $.each(this.collection.pages, function(index, page) {

                    $.each(page, function(n, cs) {
                        var title = $(cs).find('span.text');
                        title.html('Clipping' + clipNum); //always 0 or all clips are '0'
                    });

                });

                --this.clipsLength;
                clipNum = num-this.clipsLength;
            }
```

for the try here is the fiddle:

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgwow5pt/)

Comment: rearrange means .. again numbering freshly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like reset the number?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgwow5pt/2/

```
$('#content').on('click', '.remove', function () {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  $('span').each(function(i, item){
    item.lastChild.textContent = i+1;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgwow5pt/1/)

Try this

```
var htmlT = '<span><a href="#" class="remove">x</a></span>';
i=1;

$('#content').on('click', '.remove', function () {
   $(this).parent().remove();
    i = 1;
    $('#content span').each(function() {
        $(this).html('<a class="remove" href="#">x</a>'+i);
        i++;
    });
})

$('.add').click(function () {
    $('#content').append($(htmlT).append(i));
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Multiple time of creating and appending elements are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here it works

I modified your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/khaleel/Lgwow5pt/7/

```
$('#content').on('click', '.remove', function () {
   $(this).parent().remove();
    var l= $("#content").find('span').length;
      $('#content').empty();
        i=1;
    for(var j=0;j<l;j++){
       $('#content').append($(htmlT).append(i));
    i++;
    } 
})
```

Hope you accept the solution

Answer (score 0):

Well ..according to your fiddle i tried to resolve the issue. Hope this helps.

change the click event on .remove with the following:

```
$('#content').on('click', '.remove', function () {
j=i-2;
i=1;
$(this).parent().remove();
$("#content").html("");
for(k=0;k<j;k++)
    $('.add').trigger('click');
})
```